# moveRowAtIndexPath - save order number to Core Data blocks UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

in my app I use a UITableView that is filled with Core Data objects. I wanted to make it possible to change to order of the cells. So I implemented

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return  YES;
}
```

and

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {
```

I am saving an order number for every object to Core Data to use it for the sort descriptor to make the reordering persistant. So I am doing

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {

NSMutableArray *allFRCObjects = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];

NSString *stringToMove = [allFRCObjects objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
[allFRCObjects removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
[allFRCObjects insertObject:stringToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];

NSUInteger countInt = [allFRCObjects count];

float f = (float) countInt;

f = f -1;

for (NSManagedObject *mo in allFRCObjects)  {

    [mo setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:f] forKey:@"orderNumberFloat"];

    f--;

    }
}
```

This is working in the simulator, however if I test on an old iPad 3 with many Objects in the TableView the UI gets blocked for some seconds and obviously

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:

      [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
```

is getting called many times what is causing the blocking of the UI I guess...

I am not that pro with these async things and so. Did a bit try and error with dispatch but it didn t help.

What could I do about it ?

Thanks for help !

**EDIT**

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{

 case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
```

is getting called too often from my For-Loop in

```
moveRowAtIndexPath:
```

I wonder if I can avoid this !?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you reindexing the sort order for all your managed objects with every move? This could also be a bottleneck.

I remember a way of doing this that was shown in the old BNR iOS books that was much more efficient. As you add new objects, increment the sort order by 1. When reordering objects grab the sort order for the objects before and after your new destination index. Then do some math that gives you a float exactly half way between those two sort order numbers and set that as the sort order on your moved object. This way you only ever have to update the moved objects.

Comment: yes exactly, i thought i have to reindex all objects... still not really understand how this can work without, but however I found this https://github.com/zehrer/UIOrderedTableView and just used that code and it seems to work ;) thanks for help !

Answer (score 4):

Start with running Instruments and using the Time Profiler. Once you can see the block in Instruments turn off system libraries and invert the call stack.  That will show you what piece of code is costing the time.

Most likely it is the population or drawing of your `UITableViewCell`.

Whatever method is showing as taking up the time, double click on that method, it will show the line of code.

That will be the code you need to correct.

Comment: Thanks for help.  [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath]; is blocking the UI and I wonder if I could do my stuff in moveRowAtIndexPath without  [self configureCell being called that often.... !?

Comment: the call to `-configureCell:` is not expensive.  What is inside of that method?  What are you doing in the cell?  **THAT** is what is costing you time.  Identify that and it will probably be obvious what is expensive.  Double click on the `-configureCell:` in Instruments and it will show you, line by line, what is expensive.  Or post the profile and I will look at it.

Comment: I ended up bypassing the fetchedresultcontroller delegate methods with a bool... seems to work, not yet fully tested though... thanks for help !

Comment: That is a bandaid on the problem.  It is **NOT** The `NSFetchedResultsController`, it never is.  Your table view cells are taking too long to initialize, draw, etc.  You really want to solve that problem instead of hiding it.  Good luck...